# Redirection from after slash word to query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I am very new in coding and redirection in `.htaccess`.
I would need a redirection for a lot of URLs with the slug `/brand/`.
For example:

```
https://example.com/brand/AAA to /shop/?filter_marke=AAA
https://example.com/brand/BBB to /shop/?filter_marke=BBB
https://example.com/brand/CCC to /shop/?filter_marke=CCC
```

and so on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform the "redirect" like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^brand/(\w+)$ /shop/?filter_marke=$1 [R=302,L]
```

The order of rules can be important. This would need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, before any existing rewrites. If this is a WordPress site, then it would need to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string (2nd argument) contains the value of the *word* after `/brand/` in the URL-path.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I only forgot to mention that there is a slash after the variable, means the incoming link looks like `..../AAA/`

In that case you can simply append a trailing slash to the end of the pattern, ie. `^brand/(\w+)/$`. Or make the trailing slash optional so it matches both. ie. `^brand/(\w+)/?$`.

Comment: That works perfrect, thank you. I only forgot to mention that there is a slash after the variable, means the incoming link looks like ..../AAA/
Really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: @oliverkönig You're welcome. In that case you can simply append a trailing slash to the _pattern_, ie. `^brand/(\w+)/$`. Or make the trailing slash optional so it matches both. ie. `^brand/(\w+)/?$`